# Why does 赤道 mean Equator?

Tags: translation

Since 赤 means *red*, *bare*, and 道 means *way*, *path*?

Answer (score 7):

Actually there are three of these words: 赤道, 黄道, 白道, where '赤' means 'red', '黄' means 'yellow', and '白' means 'white'.

赤道 is the equator. 黄道 is the sun's track in the sky. 白道 is the moon's track in the sky. As for why they are named so - they are named using "the five colors corresponding to five directions", according to 《汉书·天文志》. If you know Chinese, you can refer to this question on 知乎: https://www.zhihu.com/question/21376627

Comment: Exactly, these words are not translated from English but are words which are already there defined by Chinese astrologist thousands years ago.

Answer (score -1):

赤 has several meanings, in this case imaginary or unreal. The equator is  a path that has been thought up by the human intellect, and so does not represent a physical boundary per se.

Comment: Strange. My Oxford dictionary also gives "loyal, sincere". That's almost the opposite of "imaginary, unreal"... But I know Chinese has such things. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, the Coriolis effect implies it's not so imaginary...

Comment: Don't think the coriolis effect was known before the equator was defined. Another interpretation is that the red line demarcates a very hot area. Indeed, if you look at a temperature map, you could see a typical red banding around the equator, although it is not the hottest place on earth.

Comment: Yes, your both points make a lot of sense. Btw, in which dictionary did you find the definition of "imaginary", "unreal"? I don't find it not even here: http://chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E8%B5%A4

Comment: Can you give a reference why 赤 in this case mean imaginary or unreal ?